# How to divide several pages of text (80.000 words) that i have to divide into 160 characters per page in a text editor?

Tags: sublime-text-2, bbedit

A have several pages of text (80.000 words) that i have to transform and divide into 160 characters max per page.

Any of you can help me do this in BBedit or Sublime Text (Mac)?

Comment: Why?  160 characters is only like 3 lines of text on the page.

Comment: Are all the character/words on the same line, or are they already split among many lines?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to make it work even if they are split among many lines. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sublime's [multiple cursors](http://www.sublimetext.com/) are really powerful. Combined with regular expressions, you can do a lot of cool things within the editor, including this.

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Find drawer.
2. Make sure Regular Expressions are turned on (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to toggle).
3. Type `(.|\n){1,160}[ .!?]`. If you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> a few times, you'll see each page selected in turn.
4. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to multi-select all pages at the same time.
5. Hit <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to put your cursor at the end of each page.
6. Type whatever you want to separate your pages. For example, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice, type a long line of "-", and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice again.

#### Why the regular expression works

The regular expression looks for any character (including new lines) repeated anywhere between 1 and 160 times, inclusive: `(.|\n){1,160}`. However, it'll only match if it can find a space or a punctuation mark after those characters: `[ .!?]`. Since regular expressions are eager (they match the longest string possible even if smaller substrings also match), each matchg will be the longest string consisting of between 1 and 160 characters followed by a space or a punctuation mark.

*(By the way, did you mean 1600 characters? 160-character pages are really quite small pages indeed.)*

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU tools installed you can do this from the command line.

You haven't specified how you'd like to break these pages aside from by the number of characters. [split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) can do this using the -b parameter. Something like:

```
# split -b 160 inputfile split
```

Should do it. Double the byte count if you are using a multibyte character set. If you're using UTF-8 you will need to convert to UTF-16 first.

Comment: Will this work only on character count or can it split at "logical" breaks, like after the last space or punctuation mark that doesn't exceed 160 characters?

Comment: It will work on lines or bytes only AFAIK. `cntr=1;for chunk in `sed -e 's/.\{70\}/&\n/g' source.txt`; do echo $chunk > chunk$cntr.txt; cntr=$(( $cntr + 1 )); done` will split every 70 words though. (note that the website output is hidding two backticks)

Comment: @krowe you can escape backticks with a backslash (i.e. `\\``), `for chunk in \`sed...\`; ... done`

Comment: `cntr=1;for chunk in \`sed -e 's/.\{70\}/&\n/g' source.txt\`; do echo $chunk > chunk$cntr.txt; cntr=$(( $cntr + 1 )); done`